# Google actions node - Invalid dialog state

Tags: google-app-engine, actions-on-google

Using the node.js SDK to create Google Home actions. 
First version works fine, but with *identical* code just new Google project I get

```
actions-on-google:debug handleError_: text=Invalid dialog state
```

coming out of this code:

```
let inputPrompt = assistant.buildInputPrompt(true, speechOutput,[repromptNoMatch],[repromptNoResponse]);
assistant.ask(inputPrompt, [{'intent': RAW_INTENT}]);
```

The exact same code works on a different Google Project.

In the working project the debug output looks like this:

```
debug ask: inputPrompt=[object Object], dialogState=undefined
```

In the not working project it looks like this:

```
debug ask: inputPrompt=[object Object], dialogState=[object Object]
```

eventhough the object is an empty obejct!

Re-deploying is not fixing the issue - which startles me.

There seems also no way to "reset" the dialog state!

Comment: solved - the ask method now doesn't support inlineDialogs anymore

Answer (score 2):

new version of ask now doesn't support expected intents anymore